# Как проверить скачавшийся файл, если хост не выложил хэш-сумму?

Tags: хеширование

При скачивании важных файлов, например, динамических библиотек, считается хорошей практикой проверять их хэш-сумму после скачивания. Обычно издатель указывает на сайте md5, с которым можно сравнить md5 полученного файла. Но что делать, если его нет, а проверить правильность нужно? Можно ли написать программу, которая сначала запрашивает у хоста хэш-сумму файла, затем скачивает его и повторно вычисляет хэш локально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> которая сначала запрашивает у хоста хэш-сумму файла, затем скачивает его и повторно вычисляет хэш локально?

Нет. Такой функционал не заложен в стандартах, поэтому довольно сложно будет наткнуться на сервер, который предоставляют эту информацию. Максимум, что можно - проверить content-length в заголовке и размер самого файла.

Answer (score 0):

В PHP можно так:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://site.ru/file.dat');

if (md5($file) === md5_file('file.dat')) {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

А если в PHP можно, наверное же, и в других тоже можно, хотя я не знаю наверняка, так как не проверял в других языках.

Comment: вся штука только в том, что file_get_contents выкачивает файл по новому. А это куча проблем:

 - время
 - память
 - второй раз файл может скачаться снова битым.

Comment: @KoVadim а разве есть другой способ получить файл целиком и высчитать его md5 сумму?

Comment: Можно по ssh зайди (если есть доступ) и посчитать на сервере md5.

Comment: @KoVadim вряд ли у автора есть доступ к серверу, откуда скачан файл. :)